# why I can't add slippage percentage greater than 1 in 0x API? what if I want to use 5% of slippage?

Tags: 0x, swaps, decentralized-exchange

I am making a DEX app and I need a mode where users will get 5% of slippage But I can't do this with 0x API, every time I try to swap with 5% of `slippagePercentage` I got this error.

```
{
    "code": 100,
    "reason": "Validation Failed",
    "validationErrors": [
        {
            "field": "slippagePercentage",
            "code": 1004,
            "reason": "MUST_BE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_ONE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve to set slippagePercentage greater than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is misleading. 1 = 100%, so 0.05 = 5%.